# Code sharing in Native script + angular 2

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have created a sample application to share code between web app and mobile app. I referred [this link](http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/videos/2016/05/12/magic-scaffolding.html) to create this app. Now I am implementing page routing in it, but not able to implement it rather I am not getting the right path to do so. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer to my own question. [It is my Git link](https://github.com/sandeepgosavi/HelloAngular) for the project with this functionality. Feel free to ask me question on it.